# SQL Join using on the fly alias column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, alias

I have some tables with a one to many relationship, and I need to join the most recent onto the parent.

The issue I am having is that the date is stored as 3 columns: day, month, year. This is because the day is an optional field if the user doesn't know an exact date.

To get a full date as one column I am doing it in the SELECT statement, but MySQL is telling me I can't use these on the fly alias columns in the ON clause for my joins.

```
SELECT
    restaurants.*,
    locations.name AS location,
    files.filename AS flag,
    CONCAT(p1.open_year,'-',p1.open_month,'-',COALESCE(NULLIF(p1.open_day,''), '30')) AS open_date,
    CONCAT(p2.open_year,'-',p2.open_month,'-',COALESCE(NULLIF(p2.open_day,''), '30')) AS p2_open_date
FROM restaurants
    LEFT JOIN locations ON restaurants.location_id = locations.id
    LEFT JOIN files ON locations.flag_id = files.id
    LEFT JOIN projects p1 ON (restaurants.id = p1.restaurant_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN projects p2 ON (restaurants.id = p2.restaurant_id AND 
(open_date < p2_open_date OR open_date = p2_open_date AND p1.id < p2.id))
WHERE restaurants.$by = :search
GROUP BY restaurants.id
```

How do I get the most recent row based on the 3-column date?

Comment: Have you considered storing a date as a [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you do the `CONCAT` when you define `p1` rather?

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
           --attributes you need from projects... 
           CONCAT(p1.open_year,'-',p1.open_month,'-',COALESCE(NULLIF(p1.open_day,''), '30')) AS open_date 
           FROM projects) p1 ON (restaurants.id = p1.restaurant_id)
```

Comment: I managed to fix it but I did it slightly differently but it was basically the same idea. I did the `CONCAT` in the join and it worked!

Comment: @Adam you mean inside the `ON` clause?